# separating data into top 20% contribution

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT priceEach,
CASE WHEN SUM((priceEach/(priceEach) * 100) BETWEEN 19 AND 20 THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL hm
FROM orderdetails
WHERE hm = 'yes'
ORDER BY priceEach DESC;
```

would this work?

I can't think how to find the segment of the prices which contributes 20% to the overall total

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your query will not work for multiple reasons.

Comment: I'm using MySQL. Data is just a list of prices of products purchased. The desired result is the range for the top 20% contribution. I already know the max price so I need to know the price ( when the prices are sorted in desc order ) at which the 20% contribution has been reached. I want to find the percentange contribution of the top price (~0.4) and then add that on to the percentage contribution of the second highest price and so on until I get to 20%. I want to know which price gets me to 20%. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is completly based on my understanding of the question. Not sure if you are looking for this result. Please try this:

```
SELECT priceEach,
       CASE WHEN SUM((priceEach/(priceEach) * 100) BETWEEN 19 AND 20 THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL END hm
FROM orderdetails
ORDER BY priceEach DESC
having Count(CASE WHEN SUM((priceEach/(priceEach) * 100) BETWEEN 19 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

no!!! you should have 
1. `group by` on `priceEach`  like this group by (priceEach)
2. `end` after case like this

```
CASE WHEN SUM((priceEach/(priceEach) * 100) BETWEEN 19 AND 20 THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL end
```

yous select will be like this

```
    SELECT priceEach,
    CASE WHEN SUM((priceEach/(priceEach) * 100) BETWEEN 19 AND 20 THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL end hm
    FROM orderdetails
    WHERE hm = 'yes'
group by priceEach
    ORDER BY priceEach DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:-
I hope this is what you want. Bit lengthy but it was worth the effort.

```
Select a.priceEach,  a.perc_priceEach_seg, SUM(b.perc_priceEach_seg) as perc_col
from
(                                
 Select priceEach, ((priceEach* 100)/overall_tot) as perc_priceEach_seg 
 from
 (
 Select priceEach,1 as tag
 from orderdetails
 ) a   
inner join
 (
 Select sum(priceEach) as overall_tot, 1 as tag
 from orderdetails
 ) b
 on a.tag=b.tag  
) a
inner join
(                                
 Select priceEach, ((priceEach* 100)/overall_tot) as perc_priceEach_seg 
 from
 (
 Select priceEach,1 as tag
 from orderdetails
 ) a   
inner join
 (
 Select sum(priceEach) as overall_tot, 1 as tag
 from orderdetails
 ) b
 on a.tag=b.tag  
) b
on
a.priceEach <= b.priceEach
group by a.priceEach,  a.perc_priceEach_seg
having SUM(b.perc_priceEach_seg) between 19 and 20
order by perc_priceEach_seg desc
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you would do this using variables:

```
select od.*
from (select od.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from orderdetails od cross join (select @rn := 0) params
      where hm = 'yes'
      order by price desc
     ) od
where floor(rn / 0.2) = @rn;
```